# Signature pad for .net development

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a signature pad that has good C# .net development tools such as events etc. Anyone have any ideas which sig pads have this capability?

Edit for clarification: We are currently testing with [Topez 1x5](http://www.topazsystems.com/products/siggemlcd1x5.asp), but it seems to have no events that we can use and is fairly limited. I am especially looking for an event that shows if it's been unplugged/plugged back in.

Comment: What do you mean by signature pad? I don't think I've ever heard the term before..

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is referring to a device that will capture a person's signature using a stylus, [something like this](http://www.google.ca/images?q=signature+pad).

Comment: @djacobson Nice link, learned something new (and odd) today :)

Comment: @Morten Mertner I'd begun to take the presence of such pads for granted - do you not see them in Denmark? They've become common in certain places in North America: for example, all the Canada Post outlets in major Canadian cities use them.

Comment: @djacobson Chip and PIN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_and_PIN) is common in the UK. I didn't sign for anything when I went back home last time. My US credit card doesn't support that and people give you strange looks. It wasn't like that in 2004.

Comment: @Brian Lyttle Chip and PIN (or its equivalent) is getting traction in Canada, too. The 'States seems to adopt these things more slowly; I remember three or four years ago a friend visiting from down south had no idea what I meant by "debit card". Anyrate, I hope someone can eventually help the OP with his question. :)

Comment: @Morten @djacobson Djacobson is correct. We are currently testing with [Topez 1x5](http://www.topazsystems.com/products/siggemlcd1x5.asp), but it seems to have no events that we can use and is fairly limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wacom release tablets with a C# SDK.

These tablets are basically dedicated signature pads.

Check out the [Wacom STU-300](http://www.wacom.com.au/displays/STU-300) and [500](http://www.wacom.com.au/displays/STU-500) and associated [SDK](http://vinae.zendesk.com/access/help) which can provide events for pen X and Y coordinates and pen pressure. (fed thru to your application via callbacks)

You can buy the device then download the SDK (free) without any additional costs. (i believe)

Comment: do you know if there is support for the device being unplugged or plugged in?

Comment: I used to maintain the SDK but don't any longer. I'll ask the current maintainer and get back to you. (it didn't have that support at a C# level when I maintained it; it *may* have that support at a C++ level.

Comment: the device has a 'isConnected' property which you could poll. (not ideal, but a means to an end)

Comment: Thanks, I sent in a presales tech question to them; we will find out! I'd perfer an event instead of using a timer, but if we have to, we have to.